access javascript function from native android
I have a react native project I want when app is closed my android native widget access to javascript function and get data from that I used HeadlessJsTaskService  but it works just when app is open

I found the answer I had to use HeadlessJsTaskWorker instead of HeadlessJsTaskService now when app is closed it works
